# Choose OpenMP pragma according to condition

Tags: c, optimization, scheduling, openmp

I have a code that I want to optimise that should run in a variaty of threads ammount. After running some tests using different scheduling techniques in a for loop that I have, I came to the conclusion that what suits best is to perform a dynamic scheduling when I have only one thread and guided otherwise. Is that even possible in openMP?

To be more precise I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
if(omp_get_max_threads()>1)
#pragma omp parallel for .... scheduling(guided)
else
#pragma omp parallel for .... scheduling(dynamic)
for(.....){
  ...
}
```

If anyone can help me I would appreciate it. The other solution would be to write two times the for loop and use an if condition. But I want to avoid that if it is possible.

Comment: The only method I can think of is to duplicate the loop into an if-statement...

Comment: That's what I meant in the end as well. My bad, I'm a bit tired. I know that is one solution but it will increase also the complexity and the size of the code. That is why it is my last resort.

Comment: I think @Mysticial has the right idea. A #pragma normally controls things that happen at compile time, therefore, the code generated for the `for` loop is likely to be different between the two -- you use a run-time condition to select the #pragma by itself.

Comment: You could also write the loop body as a massive multi-line macro. That saves a bit of code-replication. But it's ugly.

Comment: @Mysticial: Why macro? Simple function should work just fine I guess

Comment: @LihO You can't throw an OpenMP "for" over a function call.

Comment: @Mysticial: I understand you now. What I meant was to replace **body** of the loop with a function, not to replace loop itself.

Comment: @LihO I didn't think of that way. Yes, it would work if you duplicated the loop, but put the loop-body in a function call. I was thinking on the lines of putting the entire loop in a function/macro. The `#pragma omp parallel for` needs to be followed by a `for`-loop. So my initial thought of putting the entire loop in a function call, of course, won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible solution is to copy the loop into an if statement and to "extract" loop body into function to avoid breaking [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle. Then there will be only one place where you have to change this code if you need to change it in the future:

```
void foo(....)
{
   ...
}

if(omp_get_max_threads()>1)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for .... scheduling(guided)
    for (.....)
        foo(....);
}
else
{
    #pragma omp parallel for .... scheduling(dynamic)
    for (.....)
        foo(....);
}
```

Comment: +1 for putting just the loop body in the function call. Add that to your answer since it's buried under the comments.

Comment: @Mysticial: Done. Should be clear enough now. Feel free to edit it if you think it should be edited ;)